# GET in android Studio with retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, get, retrofit2

I'm new to api and how to get the data . I'm trying to make a GET method but it jus says @GET not applicable to field

the base url: https://services5.arcgis.com/fsYDFeRKu1hELJJs/arcgis/rest/services/FOHM_Covid_19_FME_1/FeatureServer/

the url with the data i want: https://services5.arcgis.com/fsYDFeRKu1hELJJs/arcgis/rest/services/FOHM_Covid_19_FME_1/FeatureServer/0/query?f=geojson&where=Region%20%3C%3E%20%27dummy%27&returnGeometry=false&outFields=Region&outFields=Totalt_antal_fall&outFields=Totalt_antal_avlidna

So if i understand correctly i should just copy the variable part into my GET
Like

GET("0/query?f=geojson&where=Region%20%3C%3E%20%27dummy%27&returnGeometry=false&outFields=Region&outFields=Totalt_antal_fall&outFields=Totalt_antal_avlidna")

but it doesnt work.

my implementations

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

Comment: `0/query?` - first letters in your params `String` belongs to URL, these aren't GET params. they starts with `f=...`, and full url is `https://services5.arcgis.com/fsYDFeRKu1hELJJs/arcgis/rest/services/FOHM_Covid_19_FME_1/FeatureServer/0/query`

Comment: So if I understand correct i should remove 0/query? and start the GET with f........

Comment: worth trying, ale "full url" changes

Comment: that error seems to iindicate you're applying `@GET` to a field and not a method. Can you share your whole implementation for the class/file?